# Uglifying application.js timeout when generating war

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I have a Grails 2.4.3 project.  It is using angular and a good amount of external js libraries.  Whenever, I try to create a war, it times out when attempting to minimized the js.  I assumed it was because there are way too many libraries so I extended the timeout in GGTS, but it still timeout.  I tried also exclude some the assets but it gave me null pointer exception at the beginning of the asset compilation.  For now, I'm skipping the minify by setting it to false.  Here are my questions:

1. Is there a problem having minimized js libraries already in the manifest?
2. Can I added the required libraries outside the manifest and get added to the war?  like in web-app/js ?
3. I believe I could add the CDN in the html rather than having the libraries in the manifest and copied to my project, but sometimes, I worked without internet access.  Is there a way to configure asset pipeline that for production to use CDN for certain assets?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation covers all if not most of your questions.

[config section](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/configuration.html)

This section cover cdn and control of minimization

For instance

```
grails.assets.url = "http://cdn.example.com/"
```

Will set a cdn URL

Comment: THx for the information;however, the cdn mentioned here is for your own code once you're in production.  My question is about external library cdn's.

Comment: would work the same ... just filter for the file name ... just an idea